# Paypal Config All Greyed out/Disabled in magento backend

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, paypal

[image]

For some reason all my paypal configure buttons became disabled and greyed out. I filled in all my store info and thats correct so that cant be the case. I am on magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From store scope select website or Store instead of store view.

Comment: That seemed to work thanks! Wierd thing now is papal express checkout wont show up for me. Only paypal shows up as a payment method,